# WeeChat decryption fails while reading from data socket

Tags: encryption, ssl, irc, tls

I'm using WeeChat for quite a while on different machines now. All instances are using the same settings over and over again. When I connect, everything is fine, like this output from WeeChat, just some certificate warnings, but I usually ignore them (as I'm connecting to my own server without any valid certs):

```
11:39:19     fnd  -- | irc: connecting to server ***.***.***/* (SSL)...
11:39:19     fnd  -- | gnutls: connected using 1024-bit Diffie-Hellman shared secret exchange
11:39:19     fnd =!= | gnutls: peer's certificate is NOT trusted
11:39:19     fnd =!= | gnutls: peer's certificate issuer is unknown
11:39:19     fnd  -- | gnutls: receiving 1 certificate
[...]
11:39:19     fnd =!= | gnutls: the hostname in the certificate does NOT match "***.***.***"
11:39:19     fnd  -- | irc: connected to ***.***.***/* (*.*.*.*)
11:39:19     fnd  -- | Welcome to the freenode Internet Relay Chat Network ***
[...]
```

Now, right after a successful connection, suddenly I get the following error disconnecting me from server:

```
[...]
11:39:19     fnd =!= | irc: reading data on socket: error -24 Decryption has failed.
11:39:19     fnd  -- | irc: disconnecting from server...
11:39:19     fnd  -- | irc: disconnected from server
11:39:19     fnd  -- | irc: reconnecting to server in 10 seconds
```

I'm using [ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) with [WeeChat](http://www.weechat.org/) 0.4.1.

```
[user@machine ~]$ weechat-curses -v
0.4.1
[user@machine ~]$ uname -a
Linux machine 3.9.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 3 22:45:16 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

SSL is on, SSL-Keysize is 1024 and SSL-Verify is off. The server which I'm connecting to is a bouncer ([ZNC](http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC)) instance. But the same WeeChat settings are working on other machines.

How to solve this? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the guys at `#weechat` and they know this issue. It's a major bug in GnuTLS 3.2.2, it also breaks other stuff like webkit, wget, etc.

Downgrading (or waiting for a fixed version) fixed this issue, it's not a weechat problem.

Follow this issues:

- https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36207
- https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36212

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a bug in Weechat 0.4.1. I found this thread titled: [bug #38496: Bitlbee connection 127.0.0.1/6667 breaks after 0.4.0](http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?38496).

> Fri 12 Apr 2013 10:49:57 AM UTC, comment #8:
>   The problem should be fixed. Thank you Pavel for the access on OS X
>   machine, which helps me to fix the problem.  Pavel and Peter: please
>   test latest git version and let me know if you still have problems.

You can get the latest version from the git repo:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/weechat.git